# Using ActiveRecord to match an array in a record

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

One column of my table consists of an array of strings in json format. I want to know how to use ActiveRecord to return all records that have an array that matches or is comprised of the same items in the array provided.

For example:

```
flag.colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
query = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

Flag.where('colors matches query') #=> flag
```

Comment: Which database? By "array of strings in json format" do you mean JSON in a `varchar` or `text` column or are you using your database's native JSON support?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, but not the native JSON support (had some bugs), it's datatype is String, but will use the JSON.parse method to bring it to an array in ruby. Not ideal, I now realize...

Comment: Since your JSON is just an array of strings, could you rework the schema to use a `text[]` column? Array columns should work fine with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching serialized data with ActiveRecord on SQL part won't be possible. You can filter it in Ruby end though:

```
flag.colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
query = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

Flag.all.select{|f| f.colors.sort == query.sort} #=> [flag]
```

As you're using PostgreSQL, there's a better way actually. PG supports native Array. You can enable it in migration:

```
create_table :flags do |t|
  t.text :tags, array: true
end
```

Then simply search for it:

```
query = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

#With Overlap operator:
Flag.where.overlap(tags: query)

#or with Contains Operator
Flag.where.contains(tags: query)
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/searching-serialized-fields-in-rails-using-postgres-arrays).